# Prevent leak after Ctrl+C when using read and malloc in a loop

Tags: c

I have to do a project, creating a shell in C.
There will be a while loop waiting for characters to read in input.

I think it's better to store characters we read in a pointer using `malloc` than in a buffer (array of characters) with fixed sized because we don't know how many characters will be sent. This way, I could use `realloc` on the pointer to get a larger size if needed.

I've noticed with valgrind that when the program has finished reading characters and is waiting for new ones; if I press Ctrl+C, there will be memory leak.
The only solution I've found to prevent this is to free the pointer after each command sent.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way to do this? For information, I'm reading characters in a buffer buf and then concatenating string to the pointer str. Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define READ_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
  char  buf[READ_SIZE];
  char  *str;
  int   ret;
  int   size;
  int   max;

  str = NULL;
  size = 0;
  max = READ_SIZE;
  write(1, "$> ", 3);
  while((ret = read(0, buf, READ_SIZE)))
    {
      if (str == NULL)
      {
        if ((str = malloc(READ_SIZE + 1)) == NULL)
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        strncpy(str, buf, ret);
        str[ret] = '\0';
      }
      else
        str = strncat(str, buf, ret);
      if (strncmp(&buf[ret - 1], "\n", 1) == 0)
      {
        str[size + ret - 1] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", str);
        size = 0;
        max = READ_SIZE;
        free(str);
        str = NULL;
        write(1, "$> ", 3);
      }
      else if (size + ret == max)
      {
        max *= 2;
        size += READ_SIZE;
        if ((str = realloc(str, max + 1)) == NULL)
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      else
        size += READ_SIZE;
    }
  free(str);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things to say here -

1. If it's important to you that your program exits cleanly on ctrl+C, then you must add a [signal handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) to do cleanup instead of exiting immediately on ctrl+C.  Note that your solution works imperfectly:  if you hit ctrl+c in the split-second between your alloc and dealloc, you would still show a leak.
2. It's arguably unimportant for leaks to be cleaned up on program exit, since the OS cleans up any remaining memory in this case.  The argument against this is that in software engineering, your program now may become a library to another program in the future and its leaks would become dangerous.  Right now your program leaks on any SIGINT; it's up to you whether part of the interface of your program is to guarantee that memory will be cleaned up on SIGINT even if the process continues running.  I personally can't really imagine this being important.
3. You definitely can't prevent leaks on a ctrl+Z, so don't stress out too much over perfection.

In other words - I don't think it's important, but I did my best to explain why it sort of might be, and you can solve it for ctrl+C if you insist.